# Kubernetes - cert-manager - error while creating the issuer that uses Hashicorp Vault

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault, cert-manager

I have created a vault cluster that uses OpenSSL self-signed certs generated by [terraform-aws-vault](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-aws-vault/tree/master/modules/private-tls-cert) module

I am getting following error when I tried to create an issuer resource in Kubernetes which uses this Vault cluster.

```
validation failure list:
spec.vault.caBundle in body must be of type byte: "../certs/vault-cabundle.pem"
```

This is my issuer yaml file

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: vault-clusterissuer
spec:
  vault:
    path: pki_int/sign/cert-manager
    server: https://vault-cluster.example.com:8200
    caBundle: /etc/ssl/certs/istio-ingress/vault-cabundle.pem
    auth:
      appRole:
        path: approle
        roleId: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" 
        secretRef:
          name: cert-manager-vault-approle
          key: secretId
```

I have used this command for base64 encrypting the caBundle file -

```
openssl base64 -in cabundle.pem -out vault-cabundle.pem
```

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be due to the expected format in yaml file for attribute caBundle. I couldn't find a documented schema for it. But, I found an example https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/61171. The caBundle seems to be taking a single line of string which is base64. I have tested this and it works for me.

It should work if you place entire base64 encoded file in one line and put it against caBundle. Refer to the link posted for an example.

Comment: The `caBundle` field needs to be the base64 value of what is in the pem file. cert-manager can not read files from the filesystem